# Spring JPA pagination iteration

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, pagination

This might be basic but the below code not working as expected.

Below codes not iterating through all pages! I am verifying this db rows count and `sum of currentPage.getContent().size()`.

Snippet1:

```
Pageable pageRequest = PageRequest.of(page, pageSize, Sort.by("field").ascending());
Page<Something> currentPage;
do {
 currentPage = repo.findAll(pageRequest);
 // do something
 pageRequest = pageRequest.next();
} while(!currentPage.isLast());
```

Snippet2:

```
Pageable pageRequest = PageRequest.of(page, pageSize, Sort.by("field").ascending());
Page<Something> currentPage = repo.findAll(pageRequest);
while(!currentPage.conetent().isEmpty()) {
 currentPage = repo.findAll(pageRequest);
 // do something
 pageRequest = pageRequest.next();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to do the same thing and I started from your snippets. I tested this solution and it iterated over all results. I start from page 0.

```
Pageable pageRequest = PageRequest.of(0, PAGE_SIZE);
Page<Something> pageOfSomethings;


do {
  pageOfSomethings
      = somethingRepository.findBySomeCriterias(
      criteria,
      pageRequest
  );
  doSomethingWithResults(pageOfSomethings);
  pageRequest = pageRequest.next();
} while (pageOfSomethings.hasNext());
```